# On which Stack Exchange site can I discuss about a technical project implementation details?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to discuss and take recommendations from users about a technical project which I would be implementing. The project is to be implemented in Python. On which Stack Exchange site can I discuss so?

EDIT: If anyone can suggest any site other then on Stack Exchange network then too it would be fine.

Comment: What about your project are you intending to ask about?  What types of things are you trying to discuss or get recommendations about?

Comment: I have problem statement I want to ask If the way I am thinking to design it is correct. Also If anyone have any specific suggestion or comes out with any flaw etc.

Comment: Sounds too broad/opinion based for any site on the network

Comment: `The project is to be implemented in Python`, looks like you have doubts about software architecture implementation if yes then there is a SE site known as [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Computerone if you suggest a site you are not familiar with yourself (as in a regular contributor) always add the advice to check the helpcenter and/or ask on their meta site before posting that question.

Comment: @rene `if you suggest a site you are not familiar with yourself`, How do you say that ? `check the helpcenter and/or ask on their meta site` See my link and I researched enough before posting the comment, now man I cannot post my entire research here. Please read my comment thoroughly. From the line posted by OP it looks like he was looking for some software architecture implementation related to python and that is why I had posted the link. Check the link.

Comment: @Computerone I checked the link, sorry I overlooked that. That points to a nice starting point. I only tried to add some caution to redirecting users if they end-up with a question being closed on that site and then that user wonders where they went wrong.

Comment: @rene That's ok.. BTW, the question is too broad and only 1 line from the OP's ques, `The project is to be implemented in Python` and that gave me a hint to Programmers SE

Answer (score 8):

Because the question you are looking to ask is more ambiguous than most SE sites will want, and you point out that you want to discuss things (which isn't suitable to SE's strict Q/A format, I'll suggest that you post your question in a Stack Overflow chat room.

Specifically, the [**Python**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) room. Be sure you read the [rules](http://sopython.com/chatroom) before you participate.

User [61612](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2301450/61612) from that room  [says:](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21990957#219909570)

> I think it's fine to discuss it here